# Exporting Images in Browser Using Html And Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I would like to provide functionality for a user to export (save locally) an image (svg) that is in a webpage but, unsure how that can be done.  I have see that you can do this with canvas but not regular images.

Example Code:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <img src="/path/to/image.svg">
    <button>Export and Save</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a link to the file:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.svg" download>Export and save</a>
```

You can also set download="Filename.svg" if you want another filename for the download.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you'd like to use something other than an `<a>` element (i.e. a `button`) then you could use this:

```
  <img id="myImage" src="/path/to/image.svg">
  <button onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('myImage').src)">Export and Save</button>
```

On the server-side, you would have to send the appropriate headers to force a download on the client side, for example:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.svg"
```